# What is the proper iptables configuration for Apache Solr on CentOS?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, firewall, iptables, solr

I know for a fact that iptables running is causing my instance of Apache Solr to be inaccessible.
How do I know this? Because I ran:

```
/sbin/service iptables save && /sbin/service iptables stop
```

Once I did this, everything worked flawlessly.

I would like to continue using my firewall however, adding the necessary rules for it doesn't seem to be working. I have exhausted what I thought would work:

```
/sbin/service iptables start
/sbin/iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Still not working

```
/sbin/iptables -D RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Still not working

I even tried doing a general ACCEPT on the 8983 port:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Still not working!

Ideas?

```
**/sbin/iptables -L -n -v**

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 215K   50M RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8983 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 279K packets, 286M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
14286   19M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    8   672 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255 
    0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 
 181K   29M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    2   164 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:55 
  148  7676 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8008 
    2   120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
11208  621K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 
 2202  123K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443 
 5372  951K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

**UPDATE (added before last rule):**

```
*# /sbin/iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers*
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     585K  123M RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 782K packets, 822M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    31867   43M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2       27  2232 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255 
3        0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353 
6        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631 
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 
8     502K   76M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
9        4   268 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:55 
10     189  9780 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8008 
11       8   480 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
12   29633 1656K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 
13    6138  345K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443 
14   14841 2635K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

*# /sbin/iptables --insert RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 14 -p tcp --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT
# /sbin/iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers*
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     599K  127M RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 801K packets, 841M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    32631   44M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2       27  2232 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255 
3        0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4        0     0 ACCEPT     ah   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353 
6        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631 
7        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 
8     514K   78M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
9        4   268 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:55 
10     292 15136 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8008 
11       8   480 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
12   30425 1701K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80 
13    6304  355K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443 
14       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8983 
15   15130 2690K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

**Even though the ACCEPT rule was added before the last line of the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT Chain, it is still not working**

Comment: One vitally useful piece of information when trying to debug a set of firewall rules, is the actual firewall rules :)  can you show us the output of either `iptables-save` or `iptables -L -n -v`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **order** of iptables rules is important, as first-match-wins.  Red Hat, like most sensible people, usually puts a blanket REJECT at the end of its chain, and adding rules to permit solr traffic - or any other kind of traffic - after that won't help, as the packet will never get that far down the chain.

If this is what's biting you, you need to do an `iptables -L -n -v --line-number`, find the number of the blanket rule at the end, and use `iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT n ...` to insert your ACCEPT at line number `n`, where n is less than the number of the blanket REJECT.

**Edit**: thanks for the listing.  See that blanket `REJECT   all -- *  *` at the end?  There's no point adding your `ACCEPT` after that, as you'll never get that far.  Try doing the `--line-number` listing to find out where you need to insert that line - anywhere before the last line should do - and see if that works.

**Edit 2**: can you also confirm that `netstat -an|grep 8983` on the server returns something sensible?

**Edit 3**: then your server's not listening on port 8983, which is why you can't connect to it even after opening up the port in the firewall.  If you had a listener on that port, you'd see something like

```
[madhatta@www mail]$ netstat -an|grep 443
tcp        0      0 193.219.118.100:443         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

The above example being taken from my webserver, which is why it's port 443 not 8983.  You're going to need to find out why there's no listener on 8983 before we can make any more progress.

**Edit 4**: you can't connect to a daemon that's not listening.  I know you said that "taking down the firewall fixes everything", and that may have been true when the daemon was listening; but right now I doubt it.  If you're willing to repeat the experiment: taking the firewall down, confirming that `netstat -an|grep 8983` on the server still returns nothing, and then showing that `telnet server 8983` gives a connection, I shall be pleasantly surprised.

**Edit 5**: glad to help!

Comment: I added the iptables listing above for debugging.

Comment: and this confirms that he's on the right track.  your current firwall rules say that all INPUT goes to the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT chain, and if nothing matches there, then it tries the one you added to accept 8093, however the last rule of RH-Firewall-1-INPUT always matches, so it never hits your rule.  Insert your rule before the last rule of RH-Firewall-1-INPUT or as the first rule of INPUT

Comment: Thanks again but adding the rule before the last line of the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT Chain, it is still not working. See above.

Comment: Let's see your new `iptables -L -n -v`, after adding the rule, preferably in your question, above.

Comment: I have already provided this above. Look for the line after "/sbin/iptables --insert RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 14 -p tcp --dport 8983 -j ACCEPT" Thanks.

Comment: The new accept rule I added is on line 14 and the last rule was bumped to line 15

Comment: OK, sorry, I see it.  What happens when, from the client, you do `telnet server 8983`?

Comment: Immediate, Connection refused

Comment: Can you tell us if the packet count on the ACCEPT rule you added (column 2 of line 14) has increased from zero?

Comment: Yes, it went from 0packets, 0bytes to 3packets 192bytes.

Comment: Nothing was returned when running "netstat -an|grep 8983" on the server

Comment: I don't understand how a listener has anything to do with this. Remember, disabling the firewall fixes everything.

Comment: Ok, I guess somehow...this is no longer working. Which makes no sense to me. I tried to telnet and it was forcibly rejected even with the firewall off. Nothing was returned when running "netstat -an|grep 8983" on the server, again. Also, "telnet server 8983" returned "Connection refused". The daemon is in fact running. I'll look into it more....

Comment: Wow...All I had to to was restart the jetti. How does that make any sense?